# Selected cardview no foreground

Tags: java, android, android-cardview, notepad

I need to do what google does with notes like this.

[image]

This happens when I select a note and not just when I press one, even if my finger isn't on the note, the card view is selected and grey.

I tried with a custom foreground but without results.
I am not sure it can be done with foreground.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, you want to implement color change and add stroke on long click?
Than you can use one trick:
set your card layout like so:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:id="@+id/card"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    ...>

  <LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    ...>

        ...

  </LinearLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Set LinearLayout background color

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:id="@+id/card"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

  <LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/your_color"
    ...>

         ... 

  </LinearLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Than change card and layout background color at runtime, layout margins to reveal card beneath

```
layout.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
 public boolean onLongClick(View l) {

    card.setCardBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#939393")); //darker gray
    layout.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#d4d4d4")) //gray
    // use this to define margins in dp, not px
    int dp8 = (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 8, getResources().getDisplayMetrics()); 

     // get layout's parent (card is parent of layout)
     CardView.LayoutParams params = (CardView.LayoutParams) card.getLayoutParams();
     // set margins in dp
     params.setMargins(dp8, dp8, dp8, dp8);
     // apply them to your layout
     layout.setLayoutParams(params);

 }
});
```

I haven't tested this code yet, but I think it should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Use duplicateParentState on note.
The childView will get parentView's state.
When you press parentView,the childView will get the pressed state.

```
<FrameLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"  
    android:layout_height="match_parent">  
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"  
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"  
        android:text="123" 
        android:background="@drawable/bg_txt"
        android:duplicateParentState="true"  
        android:textSize="15sp" />  
</FrameLayout >
```

Add

```
<color name="color_1">#4b14b1</color>
<color name="color_0">#ffffff</color>
```

in colors.xml.

Add bg_txt.xml in drawable folder.

bg_txt.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_selected="true" android:drawable="@color/color_1"></item>
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@color/color_1"></item>
    <item android:drawable="@color/color_0"></item>
</selector>
```

Comment: it doesn't get colored even if my finger is not on it. That is what i have to do...

Answer (score 0):

Tried toggling the background of the cardview via code with a white gray color depending on the state that you would prefer. Ie if it's selected etc?